# Get current location on Google Map - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I'm trying to get the current location using Google Map with AngularJS.
This is my code:-

```js
angular.module('indexAngularApp', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
  .controller('mapsController', function($scope, $http) {
    //this is default coordinates for the map when it loads for first time  

    var options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
        $scope.map = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
        $scope.map.center.latitude = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude);
        $scope.map.center.longitude = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.longitude);
        $scope.map.center.zoom = 15;

        //$scope.position.latitude = 28.699955;
        //$scope.position.longitude = 77.098159;

        //var a = $scope.position.latitude;
        //var b = $scope.position.longitude;

        //console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.map));

        //$scope.map.center.latitude = $scope.position.latitude;
        //$scope.map.center.longitude = data.data.Long;

        //   $scope.map =
        //{
        //    center:
        //    {
        //        latitude: a,
        //        longitude: b
        //    },

        //    zoom: 15
        //}

      },
      function(error) {
        alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
      }, options);


    $scope.markers = [];
    $scope.locations = [];
    //to get all the locations from the server  
    $http.get('http://localhost:4582/Api/NewCompWebAPI').then(function(data) {
      $scope.locations = data.data;
    }, function() {
      alert('Error');
    });
    //service that gets makers info from server  
    $scope.ShowLocation = function(locationID) {
      $http.get('/home/GetMarkerData', {
        params: {
          locationID: locationID
        }
      }).then(function(data) {
        $scope.markers = [];
        $scope.markers.push({
          id: data.data.LocationID,
          coords: {
            latitude: data.data.Lat,
            longitude: data.data.Long
          },
          title: data.data.title, //title of the makers  
          address: data.data.Address, //Address of the makers  
          image: data.data.ImagePath //image --optional  
        });
        //set map focus to center  
        $scope.map.center.latitude = data.data.Lat;
        $scope.map.center.longitude = data.data.Long;
      }, function() {
        alert('Error'); //shows error if connection lost or error occurs  
      });
    }
    //Show or Hide marker on map using options passes here  
    $scope.windowOptions = {
      show: true
    };



  })

//mapsController Ends Here
```

```css
<style>input {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #A5A5A5;
}

input.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: rgb(255, 244, 244);
}

.error {
  color: red;
}

.angular-google-map-container {
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 3px lightgrey;
}

.angular-google-map {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto 0px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyD7d5zEqURlPCFVM_NcsHLGSms_Pnu4-M4"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<div ng-app="indexAngularApp">

  <!--Div for mapsController Upload Started-->
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div ng-controller="mapsController">
      <!--It displays the markers links-->
      <div class="position">{{map.center}}</div>

      <div class="maps">
        <!-- Add directive code (gmap directive) for show map and markers-->
        <ui-gmap-google-map style="box-shadow:2px 2px 2px 2px lightgrey; width:100%" center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
          <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id">
            <ui-gmap-window options="windowOptions" show="windowOptions.show">
              <div style="max-width:200px">
                <div class="header"><strong>{{marker.title}}</strong></div>
                <div id="mapcontent" class="container">
                  <p>
                    <img ng-src="{{marker.image}}" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:200px" />
                    <div>{{marker.address}}</div>
                    <b>No of Customers:</b>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ui-gmap-window>
          </ui-gmap-marker>
        </ui-gmap-google-map>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="locations">
        <ul>
          <li class="text-success" ng-repeat="l in locations" ng-click="ShowLocation(l.UniqueName)"><a href="#">{{l.UniqueName}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Div for mapsController Upload Ended-->
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Now the problem is I'm not able to get the current latitude and longitude of the device. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? does `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.position));` output something that looks correct at all?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about it too. Actually I copied the code from internet. Was looking for a way around. I made some changes. I am modifying my question above, Please take a look.

Comment: see this code ... `$scope.map.center.latitude = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude);
                $scope.map.center.longitude = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.longitude);` ... how do you think `google.maps.LatLng` knows if you are passing in only a latitude or only a longitude? answer: it doesn't `google.maps.LatLng` expects **two arguments** latitude **and** longitude ... otherwise you'll get garbage back (not really garbage, but the longitude var will be misleading)

Comment: and, as you ignored it the first time ... **are you getting any console errors** - you should now, considering what you do with `$scope.map` ... hint: a `google.maps.LatLng` object does not have a `center` property, so assigning to `$scope.map.center.latitude` will fail with `$scope.map.center is undefined`

Comment: I'm Getting this console Error:- angular:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'exp' of undefined
    at angular-google-maps.js:6350
    at p.$digest (angular:1)
    at p.$apply (angular:1)
    at angular:1
    at Object.invoke (angular:1)
    at s (angular:1)
    at ao (angular:1)
    at kl (angular:1)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular:1)
    at a (jquery:1)

Comment: Finally I've a situation where Although it is working. But it's not showing me the correct location. I answered the question for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I just changed the IndesAngular.js file :-

```js
angular.module('indexAngularApp', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
        .controller('mapsController', function ($scope, $http) {
            //this is default coordinates for the map when it loads for first time  
            var options = {
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            };

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
                $scope.position = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
                $scope.map = {
                    center:
                  {
                      latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
                      longitude: pos.coords.longitude
                  },
                  zoom:17
                };

                //console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.map));
            },
                        function (error) {
                            alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
                        }, options);

            //$scope.map =
            //  {
            //      center:
            //      {
            //          latitude: 28.6315,
            //          longitude: 77.6315
            //      },
            //      zoom: 16
            //  }
            $scope.markers = [];
            $scope.locations = [];
            //to get all the locations from the server  
            $http.get('http://localhost:4582/Api/NewCompWebAPI').then(function (data) {
                $scope.locations = data.data;
            }, function () {
                alert('Error');
            });
            //service that gets makers info from server  
            //$scope.ShowLocation = function (locationID) {
            //    $http.get('/home/GetMarkerData',
            //    {
            //        params:
            //        {
            //            locationID: locationID
            //        }
            //    }).then(function (data) {
            //        $scope.markers = [];
            //        $scope.markers.push
            //        ({
            //            id: data.data.LocationID,
            //            coords:
            //            {
            //                latitude: data.data.Lat,
            //                longitude: data.data.Long
            //            },
            //            title: data.data.title, //title of the makers  
            //            address: data.data.Address, //Address of the makers  
            //            image: data.data.ImagePath //image --optional  
            //        });
            //        //set map focus to center  
            //        $scope.map.center.latitude = data.data.Lat;
            //        $scope.map.center.longitude = data.data.Long;
            //    }, function () {
            //        alert('Error'); //shows error if connection lost or error occurs  
            //    });
            //}
            //Show or Hide marker on map using options passes here  
            $scope.windowOptions =
              {
                  show: true
              };
        })
//mapsController Ends Here
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```